# Как сделать на сайте плавный градиентый бекграунд от белого к прозрачному?

Tags: html, css, css3

Всем привет! Подскажите плиз, как на сайте к блокам ниже хэдера применить плавный переход от белого к прозрачному, а в футере наоборот от прозрачного к белому? такой способ как у меня - не правильный, слишком резкий переход получается

```css
.bg-wrapper,
.foot-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrapper"></div>
<div class="foot-wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
вот на этом сайте генератор того, что ты просишь.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта реализации для реализации вашей проблемы:

1. Нарисовать в фотошопе картинку с градиентом, и затем поставить ее фоном на нужные вам элементы.
2. Воспользоваться возможностями css: [https://www.google.ru/search?q=gradient+generator+css](http://google)

Что выбрать? Если вы хотите 100% кроссбраузерное решение, делайте первым вариантом.

Если не умеете рисовать, то делайте вторым вариантом и добавляйте огромные портянки правил в css